# How to create rowspan equivalent with gumby grid

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass

I want to create a gumby grid, but I need something similar with table using rowspan. Is it possible?

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2" >
        two rows two columns 
    </td>
    <td>something</td>
    <td>something</td>
    <td>something</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>something</td>
    <td>something</td>
    <td>something</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="3" >
        two rows three columns 
    </td>
    <td>something</td>
    <td>something</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>something</td>
    <td>something</td>
</tr>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Can be fixed with nested tables

```
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="200" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="ff0000">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                two rows two columns 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <table width="300" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td>something</td>
                                <td>something</td>
                                <td>something</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table width="300" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="ff0000">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                two rows three columns 
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <table width="200" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>something</td>
                                    <td>something</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>something</td>
                                    <td>something</td>
                                </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
```